# Hundreds of requests to the same page from legitimate visitor

Tags: web-traffic

I am seeing an odd scenario in our apache access logs. We are running Magento EE and every once in awhile I will get an alert that DB connections have spiked. On several occasions I have been able to load the server-status page and see hundreds of connections to the same page, from the same visitor, with a "sending reply" status. This seems to correlate one to one with DB connections sitting in a sleep state.

At first it seemed it was a script, but upon further review it looks as though the visitor is browsing the site in a normal fashion and then all the sudden makes hundreds of requests to the same page.

Everything I'm seeing seems to be a sympton of all these requests so my question is if anyone has encountered this same situation where a non-malicious visitor all of the sudden generates a huge amount of requests.

**EDIT**

I have found 5 total incidents in the last two months. There might other smaller incidents. Each appear to be legitimate customers. I say this because their first couple dozen requests are for js, css and images. In addition the flow and time between requests look normal. I do not see anything abnormal when I look up their IPs using ip2location. I don't see any correlation in user-agents.

It might be worth nothing that when the requests start going crazy they are the exact same requests. Same URL, same referrer. For the most part the status code 200 is being returned. I'm guessing that rules out a redirect loop?

**EDIT 2**

I should add that we have an Apache reverse proxy sitting in front of our production web server which is also Apache.

**EDIT 3**

Below is an example of what I'm seeing. I've been tracking since 4/1 And this appears to be happening on mobile devices. The particular user-agent for the below is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; LGLS620 Build/KOT49I.LS620ZV3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/30.0.1599.103 Mobile Safari/537.36||
```

I've seen non-mobile user agents, at least I think, but since 4/1 they have all been mobile and have contained (Linux; Android 4.x...)

```
Date                    mthd ver        cd  url
11/Apr/2015:15:55:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:15:55:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/8700280c501950f1f993faeb85ccba1d.css
11/Apr/2015:15:55:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/4c7438d76cc21375f2edc20977c91d36.css
11/Apr/2015:15:55:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/hla/resxclsa.js
11/Apr/2015:15:55:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/window.js
11/Apr/2015:15:55:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/b099e06c740c0bba88cf773ead1d87a3.js
11/Apr/2015:15:55:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default.css
11/Apr/2015:15:55:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/css/hla_email_modal.css
11/Apr/2015:15:55:22    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/header/pipegrad.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/top_mid.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/bottom_mid.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/center_right.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/center_left.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/close.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/top_left.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /js/prototype/windows/themes/default/top_right.gif
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/arrow_blue.png
11/Apr/2015:15:55:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/paging_bg2.png
11/Apr/2015:15:55:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/favicon.ico
11/Apr/2015:15:56:12    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:15:57:22    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/order/index/
11/Apr/2015:15:57:22    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/9f4f810481e2cc3360aff338eba49354.css
11/Apr/2015:15:57:22    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/bb621665aaccc46d08af410a5ac1d7ee.js
11/Apr/2015:15:57:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/viewer/
11/Apr/2015:15:57:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/4edf6a4f84bad10345ca7a372a80c153.css
11/Apr/2015:15:57:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/08f96739f1ebeb88a47c836cfcc1e852.js
11/Apr/2015:15:57:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/pages?CUR=1&CTLG=z4
11/Apr/2015:15:57:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/imap?CTLG=z4&CUR=1
11/Apr/2015:15:57:47    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/pages?CUR=1&CTLG=z4
11/Apr/2015:15:57:47    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/imap?CTLG=z4&CUR=1
11/Apr/2015:15:58:03    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/pages?CUR=2&CTLG=z4
11/Apr/2015:15:58:03    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/imap?CTLG=z4&CUR=2
11/Apr/2015:15:58:13    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/pages?CUR=1&CTLG=z4
11/Apr/2015:15:58:13    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/online/imap?CTLG=z4&CUR=1
11/Apr/2015:15:58:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/order/index/
11/Apr/2015:15:58:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:15:58:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/d6ec89b6a821ddc341647ded882fbb0f.css
11/Apr/2015:15:59:59    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /electronics.html
11/Apr/2015:16:01:30    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /auto-hardware.html
11/Apr/2015:16:01:48    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /auto-hardware/workshop-tools.html
11/Apr/2015:16:03:40    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /camera-optics.html
11/Apr/2015:16:04:43    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /footwear.html
11/Apr/2015:16:08:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /zig-zag-canvas-slip-ons-navy.html
11/Apr/2015:16:08:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/95ecaceb80442060cba631fb71a018d8.js
11/Apr/2015:16:08:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/slider_btn_zoom_in.gif
11/Apr/2015:16:08:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/slider_btn_zoom_out.gif
11/Apr/2015:16:08:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/55c2db86cbb0bd1d7ef0b5f0f93d09c3.css
11/Apr/2015:16:08:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/3338c38ff80d2193f80497fb24bb55e9.css
11/Apr/2015:16:08:21    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/magnifier_handle.gif
11/Apr/2015:16:08:21    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/slider_bg.gif
11/Apr/2015:16:08:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/tabs-border.png
11/Apr/2015:16:08:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/tab-active-bg.png
11/Apr/2015:16:08:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/tabs-bg.png
11/Apr/2015:16:08:26    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /footwear.html
11/Apr/2015:16:31:49    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /footwear.html
11/Apr/2015:18:33:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /recreation-health.html
11/Apr/2015:18:34:48    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /auto-hardware.html
11/Apr/2015:18:36:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /electronics.html
11/Apr/2015:18:37:30    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /mini-speaker-usb-sd-white-m4439.html
11/Apr/2015:18:38:36    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /electronics.html
11/Apr/2015:18:38:46    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /qfx-cassette-converter-boombox.html
11/Apr/2015:18:38:47    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/bkg_rating.png
11/Apr/2015:18:43:36    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /electronics.html
11/Apr/2015:18:43:43    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /cobra-noaa-weather-alert-radio.html
11/Apr/2015:18:44:10    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /12v-dc-impact-wrench-5d5775.html
11/Apr/2015:18:45:37    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /cobra-noaa-weather-alert-radio.html
11/Apr/2015:18:45:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /12v-dc-impact-wrench-5d5775.html
11/Apr/2015:18:46:07    POST    HTTP/1.1    302 /checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5oZWFydGxhbmRhbWVyaWNhLmNvbS8xMnYtZGMtaW1wYWN0LXdyZW5jaC01ZDU3NzUuaHRtbD9fX19TSUQ9VQ,,/product/1679/form_key/BiEopk9TaQbDIwra/
11/Apr/2015:18:46:08    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /checkout/cart/
11/Apr/2015:18:46:10    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/4dcedb7b40a0abdec08e1d66b36120be.css
11/Apr/2015:18:46:10    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/79ff0de5dc1596b8312b1dc385728bf2.css
11/Apr/2015:18:46:10    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/8e6408fcd407e367ea233e2a2beb876c.js
11/Apr/2015:18:46:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/i_msg-success.gif
11/Apr/2015:18:46:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/bkg_th.gif
11/Apr/2015:18:46:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/btn_trash.gif
11/Apr/2015:18:46:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/btn_checkout.gif
11/Apr/2015:18:46:11    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /skin/frontend/enterprise/hla/images/bkg_tfoot.gif
11/Apr/2015:18:46:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /12v-dc-impact-wrench-5d5775.html
11/Apr/2015:18:47:48    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /checkout/cart/
11/Apr/2015:18:48:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:18:52:53    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:18:53:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:18:54:29    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:18:55:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:18:56:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:18:57:09    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /household.html
11/Apr/2015:18:58:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:18:58:46    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:18:59:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:01    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-21-50.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:40    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:40    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:41    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:42    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles/gifts-under-20.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:43    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:43    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:44    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:44    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:00:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:00:45    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /gifts-collectibles.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:14    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:14    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:14    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:15    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:15    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:15    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:15    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:15    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:16    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:16    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:16    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/special/special
11/Apr/2015:19:01:17    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:17    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:17    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:18    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:19    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:20    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:21    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:21    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:21    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /
11/Apr/2015:19:01:23    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:24    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:25    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:26    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:27    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:27    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:28    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:28    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:28    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:29    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:29    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:29    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:29    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:30    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:31    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:31    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:31    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:32    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:32    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:32    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:32    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:33    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:34    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:34    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:34    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /6-month-value-club-membership-with-free-20-heartland-dollars.html
11/Apr/2015:19:01:57    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /hlacatalog/request/
11/Apr/2015:19:01:58    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/css/43f2991d364884e81e4c3c50064587e0.css
11/Apr/2015:19:01:58    GET HTTP/1.1    200 /media/js/5bd9c4a09105aac80c84a70736b5e066.js
```

Comment: How do you know they are a legitimate visitor?

Comment: I second what w3d has asked. I would be doubling-down on this to be sure. I would be checking the domain name or IP address to see if it is a subscriber line, checking if they request images and so forth, checking the rate of access (less the obviously rapid part), checking their accesses over the past days or weeks, possibly adding a cookie and reading the cookie temporarily, adding a JS temporarily, etc. to know absolutely sure it is a human.

Comment: @closetnoc you bring up some good things to check. I was just looking at the pages that were hit before the issue which looked like normal browsing based on flow and the time between requests. I will get more information and update my question.

Comment: @closetnoc this isn't my area of expertise. Do you have a preferred site for looking up IP info? We use ip2location but I don't understand all the info provided. Usually I just look to see if the IP is outside of the U.S. How can I determine if it's a subscriber line?

Comment: I do security research- you can post the IP address here and I can often tell you quite a bit about it. What do you want to know for sure or are you not sure yet?? I may be able to help with this.

Comment: Actually I'm interested in an IP that hit us last night. It's not really related to this topic though. Basically I'd like to know if it's safe to ban the IP or not. Does stack exchange allow private messages?

Comment: Watch out for the legality of disclosing that info in your area.

Comment: @closetnoc do you have anymore insight now that I've edited my question? Do you think there is a better suited forum for this question?

Comment: This is likely a code error. I had a similar issue with some code I wrote where the code would quietly error and not close the connection- this meant that MySql thought it had an open connection and it did not ever close it. There are some parameters to control this in MySql, but they would not have helped me much so I chose to leave them alone. I just had to sort through the code with debug on and trace where it failed, when, and how. I am not familiar with your code or even how to make a guess. Perhaps Magneto tech support? As well, are you running any JS to detect browsers??

Comment: @closetnoc I actually uploaded my code to Magento this morning. I know Magento has some mobile detection, but I do not know where in the code, but that is something to consider. We will see what Magento support can find.

Answer (score 1):

What you could try to do to help fix your situation is run some of your web pages through webpagetest.org and choose the server location closest to the server your pages are on for faster results. Then check the waterfall section when the page results appear. If you see tons of entries in a waterfall chart such as one shown at this link:

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150831_N9_18BD/1/details/

then it means you have a web page requesting numerous of resources and that could be what is causing numerous requests to your server in one second. Also, any javascript code requesting server resources can contribute to the problem as well.

Comment: The problem is I have yet to be able to reproduce this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Given what I've seen since 4/1 I started looking more into mobile requests. Something of interest I came across was that sometimes with mobile devices the connection is flaky causing the device to keep sending requests.

EDIT:

I just found that Chrome has a "prediction" feature the predicts and preloads pages before you access them. Looking back through the logged issues I see that almost all of the mobile user agents are Chrome along with some of the desktop user agents as well. Still seems an application issue, but this might shed some light. Maybe the preload is what's making all the requests.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1385029?hl=en

Comment: I worked with Magento support on this and they had me run strace on a few of the processes experiencing this situation. What came from it was that it might be related to my session storage. They suggested I switch it from file to a memory based solution. For now that is my next step, but it might take awhile to get to.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an interval with an Ajax Request loading HTML into the DOM that makes then the load of the css and js files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Can you go into more detail?

Comment: Yes, i mean that you might have a javascript code in your page checking for something each second to a url with $.ajax() , but i looked further in your code and it doesnt seem to be. Another question, it happens with all visits (even you) or it happened once this time.

Comment: It is happening typically once a day, sometimes a few times. I have not experienced it or been able to reproduce it.